# Unity Character Not Moving With Axis System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am trying to make a 2D simple platformer and I am a begginer in Unity. For some reason when I hit arrow keys, my character will play the forward animation, but doesn't move at all. Then when I release it plays the idle animation. Also it won't jump either. Below I have code attached. I have researched and tryed many methods that tinker with the rigidbody but none of them work. Currently, I have a polygonal collider attached to both my player and ground. I also have a rigidbody attached to my character. I even tryed adding debug logs to show my move input. Soo far when I hit the arrow keys the moveinput changes. So, from my view I think there is a problem with the physics.

Any help would be appreciated,

thank you

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
public float jumpforce;
private float moveInput;

private Rigidbody2D rb;

private bool facingRight = true;

private bool isGrounded;
public Transform GroundCheck;
public float checkRadius;
public LayerMask whatIsground;

private int extraJumps;
public int extraJumpsValue;
private Animator anim;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Debug.Log(moveInput);  
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
{
    Flip();
}else if(facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
{
    Flip();
}
}

void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsground);

    if (isGrounded == true)
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps > 0)
    {
    
    rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpforce;

    extraJumps--;
    }else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true)
    {
    rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpforce;
    }
     if (moveInput == 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
    }else
    {
        anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
    }
}

void Flip()
{
facingRight = !facingRight;
Vector3 Scaler
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have the object you use as a ground set to the same layer values as the whatIsground variable wants.

Comment: I have already tried that @Matthew

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `rb.velocity` in your `FixedUpdate` method. Sometimes this cause errors so I recomend you to use `rb.AddForce` in stead: `rb.AddForce(new Vector2(moveInput * speed, 0));`

Also replace your double jump mechanic 'cause the logic may not be handling the jump input correctly:

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && (isGrounded || extraJumps > 0))
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpforce);
        if (!isGrounded)
        {
            extraJumps--;
        }
    }
```

I filled your `Flip` method. It seems to be incomplete:

```
    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }
```

Hope this can help you :)